# How to use ons-select in onse-ui-1.3.1?

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui

i want to use ons-select in my app. and i have added it into my code, then debug the app, but the emulate show nothing. by the way, webstom alert me that 'can not find the ons-select tag'.
so how to use ons-select in onse-ui-1.3.1?
Any help is really appreciated.
The code:

```
<ons-select ng-model="mediaTypes.type" ng-change="search()">
    <option value="all" selected>All Media</option>
    <option value="musicVideo">Video</option>
    <option value="movie">Movie</option>
    <option value="music">Music</option>
    <option value="podcast">Podcast</option>
    <option value="tvShow">TV Show</option>
</ons-select>
```

Comment: Without your code to look at there is no way anyone can help. :)

Comment: and i did not find any content about ons-select on Onsen-UI's online doc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is `ons.platform.select()` method. However it is a new feature added in Onsen 1.3.2 that is currently [under development](https://github.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md). If you cannot wait until it is released you can use the version in [Onsen UI's master branch](https://github.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI). Hope it helps!

**Edit:**

After you updated your code I realised you are looking for something different, not `ons.platform.select()`. Looks like the tag `<ons-select>` was removed from Onsen UI. Normal HTML `<select>` should be enough.

Comment: thinks a lot.  by google, i have saw someone use the ons-select on version 1.0.4, the code just like above. i'm using 1.3.1. when i copy the code to my project, and then: i. webstorm  give a error info. ii.the emulate do not show the select content.

Comment: I uploaded the answer. I think there is no `<ons-select>` anymore, try with `<select>` and see if it works well in your OS version.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now, i know what to do.